# Reverse a nested TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have a TreeMap of the form

```
TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

which contains a roll_no, subject, and marks. I want to sort students by their marks and hence need to reverse the TreeMap and make it of the form:

```
TreeMap <TreeMap<Integer, String>, String> reverseMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Okay. What is your question now?

Comment: It is a very poor design. Create a class Student with the desired attributes. Create seperate Comparators for Student class for fields like roll no, marks, name etc. When you want to sort the students, while creating the TreeSet, also pass the desired comparator as parameter.

Comment: Which map having roll_no, subjects and marks, can you please specify here ?

Comment: Both maps would have roll_no, subject, and marks, where roll_no and subject is a string and marks, is int. So the map would look like map<roll_no, <subject, marks>> and I want the map to be <<marks, subject, roll_no>.

Comment: TreeMap<String, Integer> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
Please change the variable name that which map is refer to which attribute. 

TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();

Comment: @Ben I want to reverse the TreeMap as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply reverse the comparator from the start by passing a specific `comparator` instance to the `TreeMap` constructor :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
map.put("foo", 1);
map.put("bar", 2);
map.put("doe", 3);

System.out.println(map);
```

> {foo=1, doe=3, bar=2}

Of course, withtout the reversed comparator :

> {bar=2, doe=3, foo=1}

That solution will not required two maps (the original and the reversed one).

If you want both, then use `putAll` with a `TreeMap` with a reverse comparator :

```
Map<String, Integer> reversedMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
reversedMap.putAll(map);

System.out.println(reversedMap);
```

Note that I completly ignore your data structure since this isn't appropriate so I kept my design simple to show what can be done. A `Map` of `Map` isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Also gave an example. Please tell if any issues.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        TreeMap <TreeMap<Integer,String>, String> reverseMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder((o1,o2) -> 1));
        TreeMap<String,Integer> r1=new TreeMap<>();
        r1.put("English", 80);
        r1.put("Maths", 90);
        r1.put("Science", 75);
        r1.put("Biology", 50);


        TreeMap<String,Integer> r2=new TreeMap<>();
        r2.put("English", 50);
        r2.put("Maths", 60);
        r2.put("Science", 80);
        r2.put("Biology", 70);

        map.put("1", r1);
        map.put("2", r2);


        map.entrySet().stream().sorted((obj1,obj2)->{
            if(obj1.getValue().values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() > obj2.getValue().values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()) return 1;
            else if(obj1.getValue().values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() < obj2.getValue().values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()) return -1;
            return 0;
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(t-> {
            TreeMap<Integer,String> newmap=new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
            t.getValue().forEach((k,v)-> newmap.put(v, k));
            reverseMap.put(newmap, t.getKey());             
        });

        reverseMap.entrySet().forEach(t-> {System.out.println("Roll no: "+t.getValue());t.getKey().entrySet().forEach(a-> System.out.println(a.getKey()+" "+a.getValue()));
        });


    }
```